How to get my dropdown to populate correctly
My first dropdown works just fine but when I put a breakpoint on the second dropdown controller it does not get hit?
This is my controller for the first and second dropdowns. The first controller works great and I put a breakpoint in the GetTemplateByDeptId method never gets hit?
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult HomeView()
{
    var departments = _uow.Repository<Dept>().GetAll().ToList();

    ViewBag.Departments = departments;
 

    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTemplateByDeptId(int id)
{
    return Json(_uow.Repository<Template>().Get(x => x.TemplateID == id));
}

This is my View
@model Fab4Passdown.Data.Dept


<div class="text-center">
<h2>Department Dropdown</h2>
<div class="row form-group p-4 border m-2">
    <div class="col-2">
        Department
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">

        @Html.DropDownList("DeptID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments, "DeptID", 
  "Dept_Name"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: 38px", @id = 
  "deptdropdown" })

    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        Template
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <select id="templatedropdown">
            <option>--Select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

This is my JS
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
    getTemplateByDepartmentID;
})

$("#deptdropdown").change(function () {
    getTemplateByDepartmentID;
})

var getTemplateByDepartmentID = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetTemplateByDeptId", "Home")",
        type: "Get",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            id: $('#deptdropdown').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).each(
                function (index, item) {
                    $('#templatedropdown').append('<option value="' + item.DeptID + '">' + 
 item.Dept_Name + '</option>')
                }
            );
        }
})
}


try putting $("#deptdropdown").change(......) inside the $(document).ready(function () { .... } - this is why jQuery sucks ... if that element does not exist, there's no error or warning, jQuery just thinks "oh, you didn't want to do anything after all"

agree....tried still no luck is it my url?

no idea about the URL - have you checked the browser developer tools console for errors and to see if the request is receiving the expected result? Have you debugged the server to see if the request is being processed correctly?

The reason why your jQuery is not called is you are not actually invoking getTemplateByDepartmentID, you just reference it. Try below code (use getTemplateByDepartmentID()) and it will work well.
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
        getTemplateByDepartmentID();
    })

    $("#deptdropdown").change(function () {
        getTemplateByDepartmentID();
    })

    var getTemplateByDepartmentID = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetTemplateByDeptId", "Home")",
        type: "Get",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            id: $('#deptdropdown').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).each(
                function (index, item) {
                    $('#templatedropdown').append('<option value="' + item.DeptID + '">' +
 item.Dept_Name + '</option>')
                }
            );
        }
})
}

    </script>

Result:

